# How to query on multi table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, knex.js

I have 2 table and I want to get rows of both that sorted by create date time for each row.

For example, I have `t1` and `t2` and the schema of tables are like this:

```
----------------------
        t1    
----------------------
  id  | title | skill 
----------------------
  1   | T_1   | S_1
----------------------
  2   | T_2   | S_2
----------------------
  3   | T_3   | S_3
----------------------

----------------------
        t2    
----------------------
  id  | title | option 
----------------------
  1   | TT_1  | O_1
----------------------
  2   | TT_2  | O_2
----------------------
  3   | TT_3  | O_3
----------------------
```

I want to have a result something like this:

```
----------------------------------
            t1_t2
----------------------------------
tmp_id| title | option  |  skill
----------------------------------
  1   | TT_1  | O_1     |  
----------------------------------
  2   | T_2   |         |  S_2
----------------------------------
  3   | TT_3  | O_2     |  
----------------------------------
  4   | T_1   |         |  S_1
----------------------------------
  5   | TT_2  | O_3     |  
----------------------------------
  6   | T_3   |         |  S_3
----------------------------------
```

There is no any relation between `t1` and t2` and there are only separate tables.

Is that possible? If yes, How can I do this?

Comment: 'I have 3 table and I want to get rows of both that sorted by create date time' so why show only 2 neither of which have create date time?

Comment: using union you can do this select * from (UNION of T1 and T2 ) order by date desc;

Comment: @P.Salmon, I'm sorry. That was just a typographical mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can just union your tables together and generate a row id based on the right most portion of that `title` split by an underscore or whatever ordering makes sense here (not really following the order of your desired results now that I look at it closely):

```
Set @rn:=0;
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 as tmp_id, title, option, skill
(
    SELECT title, CAST(NULL as VARCHAR(3)) as option, skill FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT title, option, NULL FROM t2

) subunion
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, '_', -1);
```